# Agile development for mobile development with Backend server for an Indie developer

Tags: agile

Hello I am familiar with Waterfall model
I am new to Agile development.... 
I am trying build a mobile application which makes http calls to server

This is my way of building application

1) Database design
2) Server side api development
3) Mobile app development

What is the agile approach for this

Note:The whole system built by only one developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Agile way is more the other way around:

- Single feature/screen/part in mobile app (Should create user value, can you make it smaller?)
- Question what serverside API is minimally needed to implement this part of the app
- Question what minimal database structure is needed for this part of the API

This comes from the Agile XP practice [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) (You aren't gonna need it).
Work on things you need now and not what you think you might need. This increases learning you get from earlier finished parts. Also you should work on implementing complete features that give user value. Users might start using the product already when just 10% of the features are implemented (for example), because it already leads to actual usage value.

If you give the working app to your clients regularly as one of the [Agile principles](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html) says,

> Deliver working software frequently, from a  couple of weeks to a
>   couple of months, with a  preference to the shorter timescale.

then requirements *will* change and you might not need all the database structures you envisioned at the start for example.

My favorite Agile principle:

> Simplicity--the art of maximizing the amount of work not done--is
>   essential.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably suggest you start by creating some user Stories to gather requirements.

So for example you'd use the following format

As **A type of user**, I want **some goal** so that **some reason**

[User Stories Explained at by Mike Cohn](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories)

Once you've outlined your user stories you can start to prioritise these  - these  could then form your "Product Backlog".

You'd then take each story and break them down to individual doable tasks - so this might be : Implement Table Schema, etc etc (I don't know enough about your project.